# Laravel: Get images by id article

Tags: php, laravel

I need get images by id article. In other words, In dashboard i have show title articles, after click on article display content article. Everything is fine except show images.

I have 3 tables in database:
Users - here I have users id and name etc.
Articles - here I have content articles (title, main content, date, etc.)
Images - here I have save images for each article (column: id, image_id, image)

..next I have models Articles, Images, Users
in articles i have:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Articles extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'articles';

    public $fillable = array(
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'subject'
    );

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

    public function itemsArticle() {
        return $this->hasMany('Image', 'id');
    }
}
```

in image i have:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Image extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'image';

    public $fillable = array(
        'id',
        'image_id',
        'image',
    );

    public function apps() {
        return $this->belongs_to('User', 'id');
    }
}
```

and my controller:

```
$images = $this->data->itemsApp(); // here is maybe problem with show images from model Image
$articles = Articles::find($id);
return View::make('users.articles')
 ->with('images', $images)
 ->with('articles', $articles )
```

In view.blade I use foreach and if result is show only content article without images.
Thanks for advice.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but why are you using the User/Reminable traits for your Image class?

Comment: I used as template from the previous model. (copy..) Model I already corrected. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need all Illuminate class and interfaces here. Name your models with singular name.

```
class Article extends Eloquent {

    public $fillable = array(
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'subject'
    );

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }
}
```

and in your image model

```
class Image extends Eloquent {

    public $fillable = array(
        'id',
        'image_id',
        'image',
    );

    public function article() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Article');
    }
}
```

In your `images` table add field integer `article_id`, then you will be able to fetch all data by

```
$articles = Articles::with('images')->find($id);

return View::make('users.articles')->with('articles', $articles )
```

if you want to get image's user call

```
$image = Image::find($imageIdHere)->article()->user;
```

Comment: I performed all the steps,  but the result is displayed (lists in img src) the entire row of DB. (I need only one column from all row where is all path image)

Comment: Problem is solved. In view.blade I had add in image src $images->image (with foreach). Thanks for all advices.